# Unambiguous grammar for arithmetic expression with Unary + and -

Tags: grammar, compiler-theory

I have just started self-studying the Dragon book of Compiler Design. I am working on a problem that says to design grammar for an expression containing binary +,-,*,/ and unary +,-

I came up with following

```
E -> E+T | E-T | T
T -> T*P | T/P | P
P -> +S | -S | S
S -> id | constant | (E)
```

However, there is an obvious flaw in it. According to this grammar, expressions like

```
1--3
```

are valid, which is an error in all programming languages I know. Though, expressions like

```
1+-+3
and
1- -3
```

must be valid. How can such a grammar be designed?

Comment: What would `1+-+3` mean?

Comment: Why should `1--3` be invalid if `1- -3` is valid? The only reason I see for that would be a unary `--` operator, which you don't have.

Comment: @sepp2k - I'm trying to emulate behavior of C language here. -- is a valid token in C, hence, 1--3 is invalid

Comment: @Gabe - It would mean -2. It is evaluated as 1<binary-plus><unary-><unary+>3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is with tokenization. You are identifying `1--3` as an error because you think it should be resolved as `1 --3` rather than `1 - -3`, the latter being perfectly valid. So I think you problem comes because when you tokenize the string you are getting:

`['1', '-', '-' , '3']`

rather than:

`['1', '--', '3']`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one extra production rule

```
P -> +S | -S | S
S -> id | constant | (E)
```

can be shrinked to

```
P -> +P | -P | id | constant | (E)
```

With such grammar you will succesfully match exp "1+-+3" as valid.

Answer (score 0):

You have `tokenizer(scanner)` problem! before passing token to parser You must differentiate between "-" and "--". you must define a token struct which contains a token type and value, then parse the token list.
Also the rule `P->--S` must be added to the production rules!!